# Split String with spaces and minus sign

Tags: c#, string, split

I am trying to split a string which contains a sequence "Song Name - Artist Name".  I've done similar string manipulations in PHP with relative ease as shown below

PHP:

```
$titledata = explode(" - ", $title);
```

This is what I'm trying in C#:

```
string[] titledata = title.Split(" - ");
```

And it returns the error "Cannot convert from 'string' to 'char[]'".  I've tried using ToCharArray() and while it runs, it doesn't work properly.  I'm not sure if it's a problem with the minus sign or the number of characters being used as the seperator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [overloads](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7h14879.aspx) that split by strings requires them to be in an array.  You'd have to do this:

```
string[] titledata = title.Split(new[] { " - " }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```